# Removing a list of letter groupings and words from data-frame populated with sentences

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` which contains uncleaned text strings

```
                             phrase
 0           the quick brown br fox
 1   jack and jill went up the hill
```

I also have a list of words and letter groupings that I'd like to `remove` called remove which looks like:

```
['br', and]
```

In this example I'd like the following output:

```
                         phrase
 0          the quick brown fox
 1   jack jill went up the hill
```

Note it's not the `br` in 'brown' remains in `df` as it's part of a larger word but the 'br' on its own is removed.

I've tried:

```
df['phrase']=[re.sub(r"\b%remove\b", "", sent) for sent in df['phrase']]
```

But can't get it to work correctly.  What can I try next?

Comment: using replace ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use nested list comprehension with `split`, tes membership by `in` and join splitted values back:

```
L = ['br', 'and']

df['phrase']=[' '.join(x for x in sent.split() if x not in L) for sent in df['phrase']]
print (df)
                       phrase
0         the quick brown fox
1  jack jill went up the hill
```

Comment: can we do it using replace? just curious

Comment: @anky_91 - I think yes, but then is also necessary working with double or more spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like it can be down with `replace`

```
s=[r'\b'+x+r'\b' for x in L]

df.phrase.str.replace('|'.join(s),'')
Out[176]: 
0           the quick brown  fox
1    jack  jill went up the hill
Name: phrase, dtype: object
```

Comment: @anky_91 but I still think Jez 's answer is better, you can see, in my answer ,there are double whitespace :-(

Comment: Got it. :) however i wanted the working pattern actually. Its clear now. Thanks both of you Wen and @jezrael.